# How to clear the RadDropdownLIst of telerik control

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a drop down which is in telerik control. I want to reset this drop down.
i have tried with below code but both are not working. 
It is a cascade bind. i have another drop down down. on selected index change of that drop down, i am calling this method, but if i have selected any value, that value is not getting reset. that value is still selected to this drop down.

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(Sqlcmd); 
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
sda.Fill(ds); 
rddl.Items.Clear(); // rddl.ClearSelection();
rddl.DataSource = ds; 
rddl.DataTextField = "Abc";
rddl.DataBind();
```

Comment: What if I tell you both are working great! You re just missing the camel case on `ClearSelection()`. You should try to create a [mcve] when encountering those small bug. A simple clean project with a DropDownList, 2 items in an array and a button takes 2 minutes to create.

Comment: My best guess on the issue is  a missing `if (!IsPostBack)` when you are binding the dropdownlist. In the `Page_Load`.

Comment: @PierreLebon Actual code is like that.                               SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(Sqlcmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);

    rddl.Items.Clear(); // rddl.ClearSelection();
    rddl.DataSource = ds;
    rddl.DataTextField = "Abc";
    rddl.DataBind();               When i use Clear, it should clear the values which was previously selected to the dropdown. I just want to clear the previously selected value. and Bind with new value.

Comment: [edit] it into you question please. It's a pain to read code in comment .

Comment: I ' am pretty sure there is no issue in Clear an ClearSelection. You must stop what you are doing and isolate what you think is not working on an other page. Click to create a new page add **only** 5 button and a Rddl.
Bind your Rddl to an array  { "aa", "bb", "cc" }. 1button clear. 1 button clear selection, 1 button Bind, 1 button select, 5th button is for want you want. In page load initialise the Rddl only if not post bask to your array datasource.

Comment: Thanks @PierreLebon

Comment: I have issue understanding what you really want. Your 1rst post was "something do not work". tested and it work. I talk about mcve and is postback. And you just make a smoke around what is binding, the multiple rddl etc. We need to get back to simple issue. A method call in the 3rd DropDownList in a grid in a car at 120Mph is the same as a method call by a button so we do button . Sorry if i sound rude I' am not good in English.

Comment: So i was right one hour ago ? it was a simple "is postback" missing ?

Comment: NO, I have already "IsPostBack". The issue is when I clear the dropdown by ddl.Items.Clear(), it is not clearing the drop down. and again when i am binding this drop down, it should bind the fresh value. previously selected value should clear. And it should bind the value according to the values are in the dataset.

Comment: Try setting rddl.SelectedValue = ""

Comment: @chambo i tried thid also. I also tried binding the drop down will null dataset before binding with actual data. But still it is giving me previously selected value.